# htaccess rewrite url query string with index as base

Tags: .htaccess, web

New poster to this place but long term user.

I have a site which uses `index.php` and then has a `viewpost.php` and `categorypost.php`.

The viewpost is for viewing the main posts and the categorypost is for viewing posts under a category such as "webdesign".

The view post slug is made up of query string such as:

```
viewpost.php?postType=services&postCategory=webdesign&postTitle=somepost
```

I then want that to rewrite to

```
website/services/webdesign/somepost
```

**First question:**

Is this the correct way to do this by using 3 files or am I creating more work than needed?

**Second question:**

If I'm on the correct or at least an ok path, how do I go about redirecting?

I have seen about 30 or so posts around this but finding it hard to get my head around it and have ended up with 500 response or just straight redirecting.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?postTag=$1&postCategory=$2&postTitle=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If these particular links can all start with the same word, it is the simplest, in this case "website". Because it avoids mistakenly using an existing folder with a missing page.

```
RewriteRule ^website/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ viewpost.php?postTag=$1&postCategory=$2&postTitle=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

But if it's not the case, you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ viewpost.php?postTag=$1&postCategory=$2&postTitle=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you for that. Is there a way to maybe put select folders. Is that what (website/other) would do? I'll give that a try once home

Comment: It does not correspond to your basic question anymore. Each case must be programmed differently, or sorted in the program that receives the information.